# Google BigQuery BI Engine - cross projects query analytics - which project should I add the BI Engine

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bi-engine

- I have access to both Project A and Project B.
- BigQuery datasets are saved in Project A.
- The BigQuery Analytics are done in Project B. We haver some BigQuery Views set up in Project B (but querying on data in Project A), and Google Data Studio's data sources are point to Project B.

Now, I want to add BI Engine to speed up my data studio dashboards. My questions are

- Where should I add the BI engine. My guess is I should add BI engine in Project B, where the analytics is done, not where the data is stored, right?
- So if I have multiple Google projects running, instead of add BI engine to all these projects. I should just add BI engine to one project, and create BigQuery views in this project, to access all the other projects data. Is this the good cost effective process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct - you should add BI Engine reservation in the project that you use for querying, i.e. Project B.

You also don't have to use BigQuery views (especially since BI Engine is not yet fully optimized for views), you can query table in project A from project B without views.